# Letters overlapping each other when LaTex font is used in gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot

The word 'max' is not rendering correctly in gnuplot. For instance, the code snippet -

```
"{\CMMI10 max} Value"
```

produces -

[image]

This could be a bug in gnuplot. I tried using the &{} command to insert some space between the letter 'm' and 'a', but it's equivalent to a full space i.e. the end result is 'm ax'.

What's the right way to get a neat representation of the word 'max' in LaTeX font on gnuplot?

Comment: gnuplot does not do its own font handling.  It leaves that to whatever support library or language is used by the output device (gnuplot calls it a "terminal").  What gnuplot terminal are you using when you see this problem?

Comment: enhanced postscript

Comment: PostScript font rendering is done by the viewer (e.g. ghostview or okular or acroread) or by the printer itself.  Gnuplot does nothing but pass through the text string and the name of the font.

Comment: If you just care about italics, rather than the specific font, can you try `"{/:Italic max} Value"` instead?